# protractor finds element in --elementExplorer mode but not in normal mode

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am getting a NoSuchElementError in my test. So I ran protractor in --elementExplorer mode to see if I could figure out how to resolve the required element. But in --elementExplorer mode the exact same locator finds the required element.

The locator is:

```
var e=browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#newProjectKickoffDate'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need to use browser.driver.findElement if you are using an angular application just FYI. You can just do element(by.css.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element does not *yet* exist when you try to locate it. Try waiting for the element explicitly before locating it:

```
browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(by.css('#newProjectKickoffDate')));
browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#newProjectKickoffDate'));
```

Comment: I was previously trying to wait using this block: 
            //browser.wait(function(){
            //    return browser.isElementPresent(by.css('#newProjectKickoffDate'))
            //});
It seemed to work for other page elements, but fail for this particular input. I don't suppose you know why?

Comment: @MichaelStack it might be that the timeout was not enough for this particular case